# Php async options

Tags: php, php-7

Is there a simple way to have a function async processed like in nodejs ? In my case I don’t care about when it completes or anything like that nor do I need to call anything after it completes. In my situation I have a set of files which a user can request and these are grouped by project. So when user requests a file from a project I check my cache if not in cache fetch remote copy and return to user. So far all works fine. If user now goes and wants to get next file from project I would do the same. My idea is to go and after fetching the first file prefetch all other docs in the project. Problem is the prefetch right now has to complete before I can return first image to user. That creates a delay of a couple secs which I would like to avoid.
So I am looking for a way to call the prefetch and not wait for reaponse

Comment: you shouldn't need async code, you have other options to trigger the caching like using a ajax head request, service workers etc to the file/action/controller. decouple it abit more

Comment: or use nodejs..

Comment: The short answer is no. PHP does not have async functions. There are other options. If I were doing this, I would use queues.

Comment: Ajax is not an option nor is nodeJS as I am using a certain 3 party library that I need to use to get some info, otherwise I would do nodeJS

Comment: why is ajax not an option?

Comment: @ryantxr yes, a queue would solve concurrency issues as well.

Comment: Because the remote client might not support Ajax this is a endpoint which returns only files. I guess I will give Async task a try and if that does not work figure out if it’s worth to port the php library to nodeJS or give up on the prefetch

Comment: @LawrenceCherone op is asking for a server solution. At least that is how I read the question.

Comment: Yes I want all logic to be server site and client independent

Comment: @MisterniceGuy *client independent*, but that's the issue, your client-side code is relying on the request to finish.

Comment: This is an optimization. This is prefetching the files while the user does something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AsyncTask](https://github.com/dmamontov/asynctask)

**Example of work**

```
class TestTask extends AsyncTask
{
    protected function onPreExecute()
    {
    }

    protected function doInBackground($parameters)
    {
        return $parameters;
    }

    protected function onPostExecute($result)
    {
        echo $result;
    }
}

$task = new TestTask();
$task->execute('test');
```

Comment: i checked its source and it forks a whole new process :) can be useful in some situations though.

Comment: I think it forks a new process for every task execution: https://github.com/dmamontov/asynctask/blob/master/src/AsyncTask.php#L199

Comment: This may not scale well.

Comment: if he runs the two functions in a separate process, why couldn't it work ?